# PowerShell: Write-Progress for Progress on Multiple Scripts

Tags: loops, powershell, progress

**My Research:**

Okay, I have looked at dozens upon dozens of examples for `Write-Progress` and observed the following. Most of the time used in conjuction with a loop, usually "for" or "foreach". Most examples don't do anything but count to 100. Other more useful examples will perform a certain command, such as copying files. No examples envelope entire scripts.

**My Setup:**

I have several scripts (thousands of lines of code) which call each other at certain times. One single script controls or calls all the other scripts. The script runs for about 15 minutes, during that time I would like to provide status using `Write-Progress`.

**My Question:**

How can I use `Write-Progress` to provide status while ALL my scripts are executing? Basically I want to "wrap" `Write-Progress` around all my scripts or whatever is the best method for providing status for multiple called scripts from a single script.

**Best Example:**

The best use of this I've seen thus far is when using the `Update-Help` CmdLet in PowerShell V3. But since I cannot see the source-code for the `Update-Help` CmdLet, this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this out. First file is master.p1:

```
$parentId = 1
$childId = 2

Write-Progress -Id $parentId -Activity "Running master script" -Status "Step 1 of 3" -PercentComplete 0

.\slave.ps1 $parentId $childId

Write-Progress -Id $parentId -Activity "Running master script" -Status "Step 2 of 3" -PercentComplete 33.3

.\slave.ps1 $parentId $childId

Write-Progress -Id $parentId -Activity "Running master script" -Status "Step 3 of 3" -PercentComplete 66.3

.\slave.ps1 $parentId $childId
```

Second file is slave.ps1:

```
param([int32]$ProgressParentId, [int32]$progressId)

for($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i += 10)
{
    Write-Progress -Id $progressId -ParentId $parentId `
                   -Activity "Running slave script" `
                   -Status "Processing $i" `
                   -CurrentOperation "CurrentOp $i" -PercentComplete $i
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

Put those two files in the same dir and from PowerShell (or ISE) execute master.ps1.  I have used this approach before to report progress of multiple phases across multiple scripts.  The key is to pass the `ParentId` of the top level progress to the child scripts so they can report progress in that same context.  If you provide a unique `Id` for each, they can get their own separate progress bar.  Or just the same `Id` everywhere to update a single progress bar.

Comment: Keith, thanks for your answer. This looks very promising. It's the labor day weekend, so I'll give this a try Tursday morning.

Comment: Keith, your script works fine on it's own, however I am unsure how to incorporate this with my scripts. I tried placing multiples of `Write-Progress` throughout my script. Only problem is it doesn't stick/stay at the top, just scrolls along with the verbose output from my scripts.

Comment: Ultimately I used a concept very similar to what you have here to get it up and working. Thank you.

Comment: Write-Progress works in Powershell Remoting, not interactive session?